# Vertically Aligning Caption with Image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to draw a caption to the right of an image.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5rcy0f5/) of the below:

```css
.captionDiv {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.leftImage {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.caption {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="captionDiv">
  <img class="leftImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" title="Template Secondary Image">
  <span class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ut.</span>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the caption text to both wrap to the right of the image and be vertically centered.

I tried using `vertical-align: middle;` but that doesn't effect text.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Would a two-column table be the best bet here? It seems messy, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **`display:table`** property to *`.captionDiv`* and
add **`display:table-cell`** & **`vertical-align:middle`** to *`.caption`* div

Here is working **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/nvishnu/v5rcy0f5/6/

Comment: As I feared, a table is the way to go... but that does seem to work perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @baum - `display: table` is fine for layout purposes. It is **not** the same as using `<table>`.

Answer (score 0):

This gets the result you are looking for:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<div class="captionDiv">
    <img class="leftImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" title="Template Secondary     
    Image">
    <span class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit more amet. Sed ut.</span>
</div>


.captionDiv {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.leftImage {
    float: left;
    // display: inline;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.caption {
    float: left;
    font-style: italic;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
```

#### Working fiddle

[see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dj6v3j8g/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be a possibility:

```
<div class="captionDiv">
<img class="leftImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" title="Template Secondary Image">
<span class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ut.</span>
</div>

.captionDiv {
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.leftImage {
    float:left;
}
.caption {
    display:block;
    padding-top:75px;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5rcy0f5/29/)

Comment: That doesn't quite work for multiple images: the second image wraps to the right of the first (and I need this to work for multiple images).

Comment: Sorry I though it was for 1 image only